# SQL Query to count number of Journey

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a scenario in SQL Server where I need to count the number of Journeys for certain period of time.

Journey - occurs within 90 minutes of the first occurance in a sequence with a new journey commencing after 90 minutes. For example, in a given day, only tags on at 11AM, 12noon, 1pm, 2pm and 3pm, this is considered 3 journeys of the tag-ons at 11am and 12 noon as first journey, 1pm and 2pm as the second journey and the tag-on at 3pm as the third journey.

For the below data how can I count the number of journeys. Which has to be 3 based on the above logic.

```
ID            Date               Day                Time
123         14-Oct-2019        Monday               8:15:12
123         14-Oct-2019        Monday               8:38:23
123         14-Oct-2019        Monday               16:47:44
123         14-Oct-2019        Monday               17:27:58
123         14-Oct-2019        Monday               18:53:21
```

It would be really helpful if someone can give me a solution for this in SQL Server.

I tried using Lag function and created a Prev_Time which did not work in all scenario.

The expected result for above set of data should be 3.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work?

Comment: can u share your expected output???

Comment: I don't see what your description has to do with the data.

Comment: My expected output is 3. 
Since 8:15:12 is when journey started so 8:15:12 + 90 mins is 9:45:12 and everything within this time is Journey 1. So 08:38:23 belongs to Journey 1.
16:47:44 is journey 2 since it is > 9:45:12. and adding 90mins to 16:47:44 gives you 18:17:44. So anything with that time is Journey 2 so 17:27:58 falls into Journey 2.
The 18:53:21 record should be in journey 3 since it is greater than 18:17:44.

Comment: I tried using Lag function to create Previously used time. It is failing at the Journey 3 step since it is taking 12:27:58 as its previous tap which is < 90. But that particular journey started at 16:47:44.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your *description*, you can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum.  To get the journeys:

```
select id, date, journey, min(time), max(time)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_time > dateadd(minute, -90, time) then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by id, date order by time) as journey
      from (select lag(time) over (partition by id, date order by time) as prev_time
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by id, date, journey;
```

If you just want to count them:

```
select sum(case when prev_time > dateadd(minute, -90, time) then 0 else 1 end) 
from (select lag(time) over (partition by id, date order by time) as prev_time
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,

The above query assigns Journey as 2 to the time which holds 18:35:12. Where it has to be 3 since Journey 2 started at 16:47:44 and 18:35:12 is more than 90 mins to that.